# On The Subject of Word Searches

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, word-search

<sup>(This is part of a series of puzzles written for [Timwi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1480/timwi?tab=profile) for a Secret Santa puzzle exchange, themed around various custom modules for the game *Keep Talking and Nobody Explodes*. No KTaNE knowledge is necessary for any of these puzzles except the final meta; each puzzle resolves to a single word or short phrase.)</sup>

---

## On The Subject of Word Searches

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ## % | ## ^ | ## ; | ## | | ## _ | ## ^ | ## ; | ## + | ## = |
| ## * | ## = | ## > | ## ^ | ## | | ## + | ## % | ## * | ## = |
| ## = | ## € | ## | | ## + | ## ! | ## + | ## + | ## = | ## — |
| ## ; | ## % | ## = | ## & | ## | | ## & | ## | | ## ! | ## | |
| ## & | ## < | ## & | ## \ | ## & | ## — | ## = | ## \ | ## + |
| ## ! | ## = | ## ? | ## < | ## | | ## < | ## | | ## | | ## _ |
| ## ; | ## € | ## % | ## ~ | ## | | ## ^ | ## = | ## + | ## ^ |
| ## | | ## £ | ## " | ## + | ## @ | ## % | ## ^ | ## ^ | ## \ |
| ## ~ | ## * | ## | | ## _ | ## + | ## | | ## ^ | ## _ | ## £ |

`CRAB,APPLE, DATE, FRUIT, FIG, LEMON, LIME, NECTARINE, PAPAYA, PEACH, STRAW,BERRY`

The original image may be viewed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeiDO.png)

Comment: [Transcribed to text.](https://pastebin.com/hqLDkYQE) Note that I've ignored the black smudge in the left column, third cell from the bottom.

Comment: Is omitting of space between `CRAB,APPLE` and `STRAW,BERRY` intentional?

Comment: I think it's because rot13(gur sehvg anzrf ner "peno nccyr" naq "fgenjoreel" ohg vg'f gur vaqvivqhny ovgf gung ner va gur jbeq frnepu).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Each characters on the board is:

> actually representing a single letter.

Now it's our duty to:

> find which character represents which letter, so that all words below can be found (as in word-search puzzle) on the board either in horizontal, vertical, or diagonal (and even in backward order!)

Some first steps are:

> - `NECTARINE` can only be put in row $2$, fully from left-to-right converting **ALL** `*` to `N`, `=` to `E`, etc.
>  - `PAPAYA` comes next on row $4$.
>  - `PEACH` then on column $3$ in backward order.
>  - `APPLE` then `CRAB`, both can be put in diagonal.
>  - From here, it's not hard to figure out the rests, in order: `BERRY`, `LIME`, `LEMON`, `DATE`, `FRUIT`, `FIG`, and then `STRAW`.

Then here is the result:

> [image]

To extract the final answer:

> Read the letters on the outer-side, in clockwise direction, starting from top-left letter. We can have `IT HAS THREE BARS TWO STARS AND A HYPHEN`.

As commented by [hdsdv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/61592/hdsdv), this is related to above board:

> It has $3$ bars (`|`), denoting $3$ `A`.
>  It has $2$ stars (`*`), denoting $2$ `N`.
>  It has $1$ hyphen (`-`), denoting $1$ `B`.

Thus the final answer is:

> **BANANA**!

Comment: But that one has (2,3,0) not (3,2,1), no?

Comment: I think the instructions point back to the puzzle: rot13(Fgnef va gur chmmyr (nfgrevfxf) pbeerfcbaqf gb A, ulcura pbeerfcbaqf gb O, naq bs gur bcgvbaf sbe "one", V guvax N znxrf gur zbfg frafr fvapr gurer vf n pbzzba jbeq jvgu 3 N'f, 2 A'f naq n O)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan oof my bad >< will edit soon

Comment: @hdsdv Nice observation! I was thinking about that but wrongly assumed about the rot13(onef) ><

Comment: Yeah, I think this-as-it-now-stands has to be it.

Answer (score 3):

**Partial answer**

First we must

> find a correspondence between the 20 symbols used in the grid and the 20 letters in the words under it, so as to allow us to find those words in the grid. NECTARINE is the obvious way in here, being as long a word as will fit in the grid with some handily repeated letters. After a few minutes' trial and error we get:
>
> ```
> ITHASTHRE
> NECTARINE
> EMARYRREB
> HIEPAPAYA
> PLPWPBEWR
> YEGLALAAS
> HMIDATERT
> AOFRUITTW
> DNASRATSO
> ```

and now

> we can read around the outside: IT HAS THREE STARS TWO BARS AND A HYPHEN.

[EDITED to add:] ... Huh, I misread (as I found from athin's answer, posted two minutes after mine). In fact it's

> THREE BARS TWO STARS, not THREE STARS TWO BARS.

I've amended what follows accordingly (it doesn't much change my state of knowledge and/or ignorance).

My first thought is

> that maybe the "stars" and "bars" are on a national flag ("the Stars and Bars" being a colloquial term for the US flag [EDITED to add:] ... no, turns out I was wrong about that, it's a term for the first Confederate flag; thanks to Mark Tilford for pointing this out in comments), but I can't find any national flag with three bars and two stars, and the only country with a hyphen in its name seems to be Guinea-Bissau, whose flag has *one* star -- though it does have three (not all parallel) bars, at least if you consider any rectangular region to be a bar. The flag of the District of Columbia has three stars and (depending on how you count) two bars, matching my misreading but not the correct reading -- but, in any case, no hyphen.

There must be any number of

> hotels that have two stars in someone's rating, three bars for drinking in, and a hyphenated name (though probably fewer than have three stars and two bars, which is what I originally thought I was looking for),

but "any number" is too many.

I'm out of ideas -- or rather I have too many, no obvious way to filter them, and so far no sudden lightning strike of inspiration.

> Celebrities? Balls of fusing hydrogen? Stars on a flag or in a logo? Asterisks? Places where alcohol is served? Metal rods? Stripes on a flag? Musical measures? Prohibitions?

Comment: "The Stars and _Stripes_" is the US flag.  "The Stars and _Bars_" is the Confederate flag.

Comment: Oh! I'd thought the latter was a rarer alternative to the former.

Answer (score 1):

Word search:

> Each character represents a single letter. We can recover each letter with various ways. I started from matching `PAPAYA` first, because it has unique pattern.
>
>
>  [image: grid]

Then:

> If we read letters around the outside, we get **IT HAS THREE BARS, TWO STARS AND A HYPHEN**

I think the answer is:

> **THREE BARS, TWO STARS AND A HYPHEN**

Because:

> A bar(`_`) represents **S**, a star(`*`) represents **N** and a hyphen(`-`) represents **B**.
>
>  THREE **B**AR**S**, TWO **S**TAR**S** A**N**D A HYPHE**N** contains three **S**s, two **N**s and a **B**.